# How to get data from list with dictionary

Tags: python, python-netifaces

Hello I have a python variable with List plus dictionary

```
 >>> print (b[0])
    {'peer': '127.0.0.1', 'netmask': '255.0.0.0', 'addr': '127.0.0.1'}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
   >>> print (b)
[{'peer': '127.0.0.1', 'netmask': '255.0.0.0', 'addr': '127.0.0.1'}]
>>>
```

I have tried everything But I couldn't get `'addr'` extracted.

Help Please.

Comment: Hello neg voter , an explanation is must for me for negative vote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
print (b[0]['addr'])
```

> > print(b[0]) gives a dictionary, in dictionary you can fetch the value by its key like dict[key] => returns its associated value.
>
> so  `print(b[0]['addr'])` will give you the value of `addr`

Read about python data structure here [Data structure](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html)

Comment: All answers are same and simple but awesome +1.

Answer (score 3):

You can just use `b[0]['addr']`:

```
>>> b = [{'peer': '127.0.0.1', 'netmask': '255.0.0.0', 'addr': '127.0.0.1'}]
>>> b[0]['addr']
'127.0.0.1'
```

Comment: This is different from what I have asked. This is extracting from a simple dictionary but what I have asked have a list too,

Comment: @Raja Ok..no problem..the notion is same..you just need to add the list index..thats it..check edit :)

Answer (score 3):

print list by its key

```
print(b[0]['addr'])
```

Comment: All answers are same and simple but awesome +1.

Answer (score 3):

You can just use a `print(b[0]['addr'])`

Comment: All answers are same and simple but awesome +1.

Answer (score 3):

You could use `get` method of `dict`:

```
>>> b[0].get('addr')
'127.0.0.1'
```

From [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict):

> `get`*(key[, default])*
>   Return the value for *key* if *key* is in the
>   dictionary, else *default*. If *default* is not given, it defaults to
>   `None`, so that this method never raises a `KeyError`.

Comment: This is something new. Thank you +1

Answer (score 1):

You may use **get** method of dict, which works on the key, and provide the corresponding value.
`b[0].get('addr')`